# Keras ImageDataGenerator: PIL.UnidentifiedImageError

Tags: tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, computer-vision, python-imaging-library

I tried to use ImageDataGenerator to build generator images to train my model, But I am unable to do so because of the PIL.UnidentifiedImageError error. I tried different datasets and the problem pertains only to my dataset.

Now I can't unfortunately delete all the training/testing images as an answer suggested but I can remove the files causing this problem. How can I detect the error causing files?

Comment: Make a script that opens each image iteratively using PIL, and then print which ones fail.

Comment: Sometimes there are other configuration files along with images, especially in large datasets. Make a custom loop, iterate through each subfolder and image, and check whether the extension is correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a common problem particularly if you download images from say google. I developed a function that given a directory, it will go through all sub directories and check the files in each sub directory to ensure the have proper extensions and are valid image files. Code is provided below. It returns two lists. good_list is a list of valid image files and bad_list is a list of invalid image files. You will need to have Opencv installed.If you do not have it installed use pip install opencv-contrib-python.

```
def test_images(dir):
    import os
    import cv2
    bad_list=[]
    good_list=[]
    good_exts=['jpg', 'png', 'bmp','tiff','jpeg', 'gif'] # make a list of acceptable image file types
    for klass in os.listdir(dir) :  # iterate through the sub directories 
        class_path=os.path.join (dir, klass) # create path to sub directory 
        if os.path.isdir(class_path):
            for f in os.listdir(class_path): # iterate through image files
                    f_path=os.path.join(class_path, f) # path to image files
                    ext=f[f.rfind('.')+1:] # get the files extension
                    if ext  not in good_exts:
                            print(f'file {f_path}  has an invalid extension {ext}')
                            bad_list.append(f_path)                    
                    else:
                        try:
                            img=cv2.imread(f_path)
                            size=img.shape
                            good_list.append(f_path)
                        except:
                            print(f'file {f_path} is not a valid image file ')
                            bad_list.append(f_path)
        else:
            print(f'** WARNING ** directory {dir} has files in it, it should only contain sub directories')

    return good_list, bad_list
```

Comment: Thank you. It helped.