# UnidentifiedImageError: cannot identify image file when training CNN model with binary class

Tags: python, tensorflow, image-processing, keras, conv-neural-network

I am getting errors when training my CNN model for image binary classification. I am working with keras, tensorflow, ImageDataGenerator. And here is my code:

```
batch_size = 64
img_width = 200
img_height = int(img_width/640*480)

train_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1./255,
    shear_range=0.2,
    zoom_range=0.2,
    horizontal_flip=True,
    validation_split=0.2) # set validation split

train_generator = train_datagen.flow_from_directory(
    'train',
    target_size=(img_height, img_width),
    batch_size=batch_size,
    class_mode='binary',
    subset='training') # set as training data

validation_generator = train_datagen.flow_from_directory(
    'train', # same directory as training data
    target_size=(img_height, img_width),
    batch_size=batch_size,
    class_mode='binary',
    subset='validation') # set as validation data
```

The model :

```
# Making our CNN Model
from keras.layers import Conv2D,MaxPooling2D,Flatten,Dense,Dropout
from keras.models import Sequential
model = Sequential([
    Conv2D(32,(3,3),activation="relu",input_shape =(img_height, img_width,3)),
    Conv2D(150,kernel_size=(3,3),activation='relu'),
    MaxPooling2D(4,4),
    Conv2D(120,kernel_size=(3,3),activation='relu'),    
    Conv2D(80,kernel_size=(3,3),activation='relu'),    
    Conv2D(50,kernel_size=(3,3),activation='relu'),
    MaxPooling2D(4,4),
    Flatten() ,    
    Dense(120,activation='relu') ,    
    Dense(100,activation='relu') ,    
    Dense(50,activation='relu') ,        
    Dropout(rate=0.5) ,            
    Dense(1,activation='sigmoid') ,
])

model.compile(optimizer =Adam(learning_rate=0.001),loss='binary_crossentropy',metrics=['accuracy'])
history = model.fit_generator(train_generator,
                              steps_per_epoch = train_generator.samples // batch_size,
                              validation_data = validation_generator, 
                              validation_steps = validation_generator.samples // batch_size,
                              epochs = nb_epochs)
```

But, i got these **UnidentifiedImageError: cannot identify image file** errors when training the model:

```
    UnknownError: Graph execution error:
    
    2 root error(s) found.
      (0) UNKNOWN:  UnidentifiedImageError: cannot identify image file <_io.BytesIO object at 0x7f7ffe3c1f50>
   ................
      File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/PIL/Image.py", line 2896, in open
        "cannot identify image file %r" % (filename if filename else fp)
    ................
    PIL.UnidentifiedImageError: cannot identify image file <_io.BytesIO object at 0x7f7ffe3c1f50>
    
    ................
      (1) UNKNOWN:  UnidentifiedImageError: cannot identify image file <_io.BytesIO object at 0x7f7ffe3c1f50>
    Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/keras_preprocessing/image/utils.py", line 114, in load_img
    img = pil_image.open(io.BytesIO(f.read()))

  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/PIL/Image.py", line 2896, in open
    "cannot identify image file %r" % (filename if filename else fp)

PIL.UnidentifiedImageError: cannot identify image file <_io.BytesIO object at 0x7f7ffe3c1f50>
```

How can I solve this, in order to finish the training?

Thanks

Comment: Consider that one of your images is corrupt and cannot be loaded.

Comment: thank for your advice. i just got rid of the corrupted images, and now it works fine

Comment: This seems highly related to your problem: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64225718/keras-imagedatagenerator-pil-unidentifiedimageerror